# Add an existing DataSet to Report .rdlc

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, dataset, rdlc

I have a Report.
I need to create another one, similar to the one I have. So I created a second report by copying the first one.
Then I created a new DataSet for the new report. I created it also by copying the original dataset (from the first report), and changing the name.
Now, when I want to add the new DataSet in the new Report, it doesn't appear in DataSet option in "new Dataset.."

[image]

What am I missing? Why can't I see the DataSet that I've created?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I solve this. The problem was that when I copied the DataSet, I changed the name of the new one, but in the code behind, the name didn't change. So, I open the DataSet with XML Editor, edit Name, save, re-compile, and it appeared!

Answer (score 1):

You could try opening the rdlc file with an xml editor and manually copying out the data source and into your new one.
I'm not sure why it wouldn't appear in your dropdown, I don't usually use that interface for rdlcs

Comment: It should be just a matter of finding the DataSources Branch and copying it out. Oh and always take a backup before you change any XML built by a tool (Or maybe that only goes for places like this that don't use Version Control *Shudder*)